# how to get schema registry- url and api key?

Tags: confluent-schema-registry

In the confluent site I built a schema, and I want to connect the schema via python and kafka. For that I need the schema URL and an API key

I am trying to get the schema URL and API key, in a video there is a **schema registry** button but I cant see it. how can I get this info?

I did not find the relavent info

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I am facing the same problem.